# How do I get this custom font to work?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to get a font named 'CorleoneDue' to display on a website I'm currently working on. BTW, the font is what was used for The Godfather movies.

I downloaded the font from here:
http://www.dafont.com/corleone.font

I converted the ttf file to a woff file here:
https://andrewsun.com/projects/woffjs/woffer-woff-font-converter/

And this is the css rule I unsuccessfully used:

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'CorleoneDue';
  src: url('fonts/CorleoneDue.ttf') format('truetype');
  src: url('fonts/CorleoneDue.woff') format('woff');

}
```

Can anyone please help me to successfully get this font to render/display on my website?

EDIT:

I followed the directions from one of the commenters (Andrei), and I'm still having no luck. The current CSS rule has been updated to:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: CorleoneDue, sans-serif;
    src: url('corleonedue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('corleonedue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('corleonedue-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('corleonedue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('corleonedue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('corleonedue-webfont.svg#corleone_dueregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

The CSS for the `<h1>` tag (and class) I want to use the font for is:

```
.header-text {
    font-family: CorleoneDue;
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS rule to any element you want displayed with this font:

```
font-family: CorleoneDue, fantasy;
```

You can replace `fantasy` with another generic font family (if you think your font is best replaced by another generic family: `serif`, `sans-serif`, `monospace`, `cursive`). The font will only be substituted with the default font set for that generic family in two cases:

1. The browser/system cannot read any of the provided font files you provided.
2. The font file fails to load (server fault, etc...). Chances that your page loads and the font file doesn't are minimal (if they are on the same server) - so you shouldn't worry about this.

However, regarding point `1.`, you should keep in mind that `.ttf` and `.woff` formats are not enough to display your font cross-browser. Perhaps You should try a better web font generator, such as [SquirrelFonts](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). I'm not endorsing it, i just named it as it's big. You should do your own research and find the one that suits your goal best.

If you want to know how generic families are rendered by your system (when the font file doesn't load), here's a sample of each:

```css
div { text-align: center; }
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1:nth-child(1) { font-family: cursive; }
h1:nth-child(2) { font-family: sans-serif; }
h1:nth-child(3) { font-family: serif; }
h1:nth-child(4) { font-family: monospace; }
h1:nth-child(5) { font-family: fantasy; }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Cursive</h1>
  <h1>Sans Serif</h1>
  <h1>Serif</h1>
  <h1>Monospace</h1>
  <h1>Fantasy</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to check if the CSS is loaded. Check if the path to the font files is correct (they should be in the a `fonts` folder placed at the same level as your CSS file). Check console for any errors. Also, you can safely remove all the `'`s from your CSS. They are only needed if your file names or font names contain spaces. If it's still not loading, maybe your browser doesn't know how to read `.woff` or `.ttf`. Try a more complete web font generator.

Comment: The directory path seems to be OK, and there are no errors in the console. I've also edited my question to elaborate on the changes I've made to the code.

Comment: You are only defining the `font-weight: normal;`  of your font, but `.header-text` is `bold`. You should match those. (Change `font-weight: normal;` to `font-weight: bold;` in your `@font-face`.)

Comment: It's still not working, even after I made the changes you recommended. What else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: No idea, but it works for me: [CorleoneDuo](http://websiter.ro/assets/corleoneDuo/corleonedue-demo.html). Have you inspected `.header-text` to see what is setting its `font-family`? I bet it's a stronger selector than yours.

Comment: Yes, I've inspected the header-text class to no avail. This is bugging me so much. I've never used @font-face before and this is pretty discouraging. I notice the link you're using is named 'CorleoneDuo' not 'CorleoneDue'. I don't think that makes much of a difference though.

Comment: What do you mean "to no avail". It has another `font-family`, right? What's that `font-family` and what rule is setting it? From what CSS, at what line? What are you inspecting it with? The only other thing I can think of is you are having an error in your CSS file and your `@font-face` is never parsed. Check for any unclosed curly brackets.

Comment: I finally got it to work! I'm exactly not sure what I did, but it's finally working.

I suspect that it had something to do with me changing the name of the font to all lowercase 'corleonedue' and deleting the sans-serif fallback from the @font-face declaration.

I'm on the verge of dancing right now. Thanks Andrei!

Comment: @Adrian check your font folder path. I mean where you put your font.